# Why are artifacts showing when I switch to render mode?

Tags: rendering

[image]First experience with render mode while working level one, blender guru, donut tutorial. Artifacts are showing when I switch from "solid" to "render". Why is this happening? What (if anything) do I do about it? Did I miss a step?

Comment: That's a graphics driver issue. Check that your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and update your graphics driver.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, ha! I suspected my equipment might not adequate. Now, to learn about graphics drivers. Thank you.